# How to maintain page position on window.location change?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, yii2

```
var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();
        $('html').scrollTop(scroll);
```

Whenever i use the code beow, the position of my page will move to the top. I tried using the code above but it will only maintain position on refresh. How can i do so with window.location?

```
$myid = $(this).val();

window.location = '?myid=' + myid;
```

Comment: You cannot store the previous focused `id` in your JavaScript because it is client-side. You could instead store the id in a PhP `$_SESSION` variable, and check `if( isset( $_SESSION['id'] ) ) { /* put it in your window.location */ }`.

Answer (score 0):

You can do by adding id element to html element based on id which you are passing in url like below.

for example in url myid is 7. Add id to any html element like

```
<div id="section-<?ph echo (isset($_GET['myid']) && $_GET['myid'] != '') ? $_GET['mid'] : ''; ?>">
....
</div>
```

and in end of the file add below js code like below.

```
<?php
if(isset($_GET['myid']) && $_GET['myid'] != ''){
echo "<script>$('#section-'<?php echo $_GET['myid'];?>).animate({ scrollTop: $(hashText).offset().top }, 1000);</script>";
}
?>
```

after page load, page will scroll to that particular section. Hope this will help you.